# popover callback address the popover

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I created a popover with callback function.
I want that the function will address the popover and do with it something.
for example I got tow sorts of popovers "class a" and "class b".
I want that when I trigger popover class a I will get an alert "a" and when I trigger popover class b I will get an alert "b".
this is what I have done so far...

```
//create callback for popover
var tmp=$.fn.popover.Constructor.prototype.show;
$.fn.popover.Constructor.prototype.show=function(){
tmp.call(this);
if(this.options.callback){
   this.options.callback();
   }
}

//create the popover
 $("#some_div").popover({
  html:true,
  content:"<div class='a'>I want that now will jump alert box that will state the class name of this div</div>",
 trigger: "hover",
 callback:function(){
                     alert("all I managed to do is output hello"); 

 }
 });
```

thanks to the helpers

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by class `a` and `b` elements. You generate a popover only for the `some_div` element. So where will be the class `b` div?

Comment: clss a or b is the divs in the content of the pop-over... my question is how I can get to the content of the popover within the callback... I tryied using "this" selector for example: $(this).attr('class'); but I missing something.

Comment: Not sure if i fully understand what you mean, but is this what you are looking for [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/mzeqyojp/) ?

Comment: perfect!!! thanks!! I didnt know that I can access content by using $(this.content)

Comment: @misha312 - Sure, no problem. Have fun.